# How can I add interactive content to a Bootstrap popover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a website that displays a big [amMap](http://www.amcharts.com/javascript-maps/). The map doesn't need to be visible all the time, so I want to hide the map and only display it when a user clicks a button. Bootstrap's popover seems like the perfect way to handle this.

Here's the basic idea:

```html
<button id="mapbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right">Map</button>
<div id="mapcontent" style="display: none;">
    <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('#mapbutton').popover({
        html: true,
        content: function() {
            return $('#mapcontent').html();
        }
    });
});
```

Here's what I see:

[image: screenshot]

I have 2 problems:

1. The displayed map is not interactive. I can't click on it. It looks like a static picture. I'm not sure how to get it interactive. None of the [popover options](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-usage) look like they'll fix the interactivity issue.
2. The tooltip window doesn't scale appropriately. I'm guessing there's some CSS stuff I've gotta do to fix this.

How can I solve these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**

Bind the events after popover content be loaded, using event `shown.bs.popover`:

```
    $('#mapbutton').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
        $('#mapMinus').click(MyMap.ZoomOut);
        $('#mapPlus').click(MyMap.ZoomIn);
        $('#mapLeft').click(MyMap.GoLeft);        
        [...]
    })
```

** UPDATE:

Creating your own "popover", by reusing bootstrap classes:

```
<a id="mypopover">
    Lorem Ipsum    
</a>
<div id="popoverContent" class="popover fade bottom in">
    <div class="arrow" style="left: 9.375%;"></div>
    <div class="popover-content">
        <a id="clickmewouldntwork">Event: Click me! (after load page, not binding after popover)</a>
        <div id="gotit"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.popover {
    max-width: none;
    top: 20px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#clickmewouldntwork').click(function(){
    $('#gotit').append('#');
});

$('#mypopover').click(function(){
    var $target = $('#popoverContent');
    $target.toggle(!$target.is(':visible'));
});
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhtWL/2/)

**Question 2**

You have to overwrite bootstrap `.popover { max-width: 276px; }`:

```
     .popover {
          max-width: none;
     }
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhtWL/1)

Comment: Your answer to my first question isn't what I'm hoping for. There are a lot of [events](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptmaps/AmMap#events) that are possible with this map, and I shouldn't have to re-implement every single one of them. Besides, I'm not sure it's possible.... This seems like some sort of focus thing - like I need to set the focus on the div inside the popup. Your answer to question 2, though, is spot on!

Comment: If map is a library.. as far as I know, it won't be possible because bootstrap popover won't use the elements to show up in popover. It will recreate HTML tags, so the events will be lost.. The solution would be you create your own Popover..

Comment: Ahhhh, ok, that's what I needed to know! That explains why it appears as a static image. I'll have to come up with some other method, then.

Comment: You've definitely helped a lot. I'm gonna spend some time playing with this. Thanks very much!

Comment: I ended up solving this by using a [Modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals). It more or less achieves the same thing as the popover but can deal with dynamic content. Thanks again for your help!